# If (dateTimePicker's date is before this month) then... else

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement, datetimepicker

I'm busy making an application in C#. No code yet but what I need to check is if the month in `dateTimePicker1` is before this month. If the month in `dateTimePicker1` is before the current month it needs to close the app.

Basically what I need is this:

```
if (dateTimePicker1's month is before current month)
{
    System.Environment.Exit(1);
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: What is `dateTimePicker1`? Sorry, but we need more code here.

Comment: Let me suggest you finish your own code and then come back with a *real* problem.

Comment: @miparnisari I don't have any code yet. Thats the problem. dateTimePicker1 is a DateTimePicker from the Toolbox in C#. It's just the name of the DateTimePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden textboxes seem to be a strange alternative to taking advantage of the DateTimePicker and the DateTime class as a 'not equals' comparison isn't going to be an effective check

You could try something like this as Month is an int:

```
var chosenDate = datePicker.Value;
if(chosenDate.Month < DateTime.Now.Month){
     System.Environment.Exit(1);
}
else{
     //Do nothing
}
```

I'd recommend reading up on the controls or browsing/trying tutorials first

Comment: Thanks :). Yeh the hidden textbox thing is a bit of an odd one you're right. Ill go ahead and try this :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. What I did was I dragged in another `DateTimePicker`from the ToolBox as well as a `TextBox`. I then set the text in the added `TextBox` to the text in the newly added `DateTimePicker`. I also hid both of them so they can't be seen when the program is running. Code Here:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker2.Text;
    textBox1.Visible = false;
    dateTimePicker2.Visible = false;
}
```

I then made an If-statement as follows:

```
if (textBox1.Text != dateTimePicker2.Text)
{
    System.Environment.Exit(1);
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

> BTW I also set the `Format` to Custom in the `Properties` Menu and set
>   the `CustomFormat` to "MMMMMMMMMM".